# Android: Button press occuring multiple times when button is being cilcked

Tags: android, react-native, button, events

I have a react native application in which in android whenever there is a low memory situation, the system is killing some process but the event handler remains, so when the user comes back in that situation and then clicks a button, the button click is registered multiple times depending on how many times the user has gone in the background.

We can reproduce it using the "Don't keep activities" when in the background option in developer options.

So, I found a solution to just kill the app process whenever it goes in the background but it will affect user experience hence I want some different solution for this issue.

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        {
        super.onDestroy();
        int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even handler can remains only if the Listener/watcher/observer is registered OUTSIDE that Activity (a Service, a Thread, etc...) and some reference to that Activity still persist in memory in one variable, or if it is STATIC. Without a complete code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @emandt Well the mainactivity.java is vanilla, and there is no type of definition we have made ourselves, so I might not have given the reason that clearly, but have you seen this issue anywhere?